# Simulating inheritance with WF 4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I would like to achieve the following: all the workflows created should have the same structure (validation, execution, save results), and all the developers should implement those three stages (maybe leaving it empty). Similar to inheritance with abstract methods.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom activity with those three steps as properties and use that as the base for all your workflows.

Comment: could I expose that in a WCF service? each of them with different contract?